# Exception: The application attempted to create more than one JMS session on the same JMS connection

Tags: java, spring, jboss, ibm-mq, spring-jms

`Spring 4.x`, `JBoss EAP 6.4`, `IBM MQ 7.5`. `JNDI` based lookup `ConnectionFactory` and `Queue`s.

The following exception occurs while starting the server:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: MQJCA1018: Only one session per connection is allowed.
The application attempted to create more than one JMS session on the same JMS connection. This exception occurs only if the application is running in a managed environment.
Modify the application so that it creates only one JMS session on a JMS connection.
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:146)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:91)
    at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionWrapper.createSession(ConnectionWrapper.java:133)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:192) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.initializeConsumers(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:265) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doInitialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:200) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.initialize(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:198) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 40 more
```

**The `JMS` configuration:**

```
    @Bean
    @Conditional(JmsConditionWMQ.class)
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer jmsContainerFactoryWMQ(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency(getConcurrency());
        factory.setAutoStartup(new Boolean(this.getAutoStartup()));
        factory.setDestinationName("jndiName");

        factory.setDestinationResolver(jndiDestinationResolver());

        return factory;
}

@Bean
public JndiDestinationResolver jndiDestinationResolver() {
    JndiDestinationResolver jdr = new JndiDestinationResolver();
    return jdr;
}

@Bean
@Conditional(JmsConditionWMQ.class)
public ConnectionFactory websphereMQConnectionFactory() {
    ConnectionFactory cf = null;
    try {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean connection = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        connection.setJndiName(connectionFactoryName);
        connection.setProxyInterface(ConnectionFactory.class);
        connection.afterPropertiesSet();
        cf = (ConnectionFactory) connection.getObject();
    } catch(NamingException e) {
        LOG.error("InQueue exception", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return cf;
}
```

**JBoss EAP 6.4 Standalone-full.xml**

```
<resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.7.rar">
<archive>
    wmq.jmsra-7.5.0.7.rar
</archive>
<transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
<connection-definitions>
    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/MQ/ConnectionFactory" pool-name="MQConnectionFactory">         
    </connection-definition>
</connection-definitions>
<admin-objects>
    <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:/MQ/INQUEUE" pool-name="INQUEUE">
        <config-property name="baseQueueName">
            INQUEUE
        </config-property>
    </admin-object>
</admin-objects>
```

**The Listener:**

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${jms.jndi.inqueue}", containerFactory = "jmsContainerFactoryWMQ", selector = "version='001'")
public void onMessageVersion1(Message message) throws JMSException {
    processMessageHeaderVersionMatched(message);
}
```

Comment: From this line:

        at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.initializeConsumers(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:265) [spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

I'd first look into the @JmsListener annotation being the culprit. Do you have more than one of those in your code?

Comment: @MattPavlovich Yes, I have several of these with different 'selectors'

Comment: Removed all other references to JMSListener however, same exception

Comment: What is your 'concurrency' set to?

Comment: @DougGrove It is set to "1-5"

Comment: set it to 1.  Only one session per connection.